# CheckboxSelectMultiple not displaying checkboxes with Django-Material

Tags: python, django, checkbox

I'm fairly new to Django so please bear with me.

I'm using a ModelForm along with Django-Material (By Viewflow) and it's working really well expect for one thing. It doesn't display checkboxes.

My 'Person' model has a ManyToMany relationship with 'Problem' and I've set the form to show checkboxes as so -

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude = ('',)
        widgets = {
            'problems': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        }
```

But it shows up like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1YHG.png)

When I remove the Material template the checkboxes show up [properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRO6E.png)

I'm not really sure if there's a problem with Django-Material or something I may have missed. Help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The indendation on the code provided is wrong.

Comment: Oops, that was just a copy-paste mistake. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it was not implemented in time when question was.

Not it works as expected and in addition could be rendered in several columns

http://forms.viewflow.io/demo/hospital/

Comment: that url returns 404

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so it turned out that they haven't included that functionality in Django-Material yet